# Yii Framework Cannot use a scalar value as an array in CMap.php

Tags: php, nginx, yii, centos

I'm trying to deploy my system (made in Yii framework) on a new server using CENTOS 7 + NGinx + PHP-Fpm + PHP 5.3.

The system is working right on the current server that uses Apache + PHP5.3, but when I try to deploy it on the new configuration (CENTOS 7 + NGinx + PHP-Fpm + PHP 5.4) the php launch the errors below:

```
2015/11/15 11:44:21 [error] 2262#0: *11 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/livreto/web/site/production/current/yii/collections/CMap.php on line 294
```

The trace is: [image: Trace]

I did a php downgrade to php5.3 but the problem persists.

I'd like know what is the problem with my new configuration?

Anyone know how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is part of my Yii `config/main.php`

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/params.php'),
    [...],
);
```

The problem was that `params.php` didn't return an array. I literally forgot to write the `return` keyword in front of the array.

Hope that helps!